# No recibo notificaciones push firebase en swift 5 en mis dispositivos

Tags: firebase, swift, xcode, firebase-messaging

esta es mi primera pregunta en el foro.

He seguido el tutorial de aquí:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UNItGXEE9vM&t=289s

Pero no recibo ninguna notificación.

Estoy programado con la ultima versión de xcode y swift

```
//  AppDelegate.swift
//  PruebaNotificacionPush-IOS
//
//  Created by Grupo csm on 1/8/22.


import UIKit
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseMessaging
@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        
        
        //CREO PROTOCOLO
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
          options: authOptions,
          completionHandler: { _, _ in })
          
        //MUESTRA VENTANA PARA ACEPTAR NOTIFICACIONES
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        //------------------------------------------
        
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        
        
        return true
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }


}

//SE REQUIERE HACER EXTENSION PARA QUE FUNCIONE LOS PUSH
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate{
    
    //PONER NOTIFICACIONES EN PRIMER PLANO
    
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        
        completionHandler([.banner, .badge, .sound])
                          
        }
              
}

extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate{
    
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
        debugPrint("FCM token \(String(describing: fcmToken))")    }
    
    
    /*
     func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
         debugPrint("FCM token \(fcmToken)")    }
     
     
     
     */
    
    
    
}
```

log:

```
2022-08-01 13:09:43.925945+0200 PruebaNotificacionPush-IOS[2772:92821] 9.3.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.9.3.0 started
2022-08-01 13:09:43.926221+0200 PruebaNotificacionPush-IOS[2772:92821] 9.3.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see http://goo.gl/RfcP7r)
2022-08-01 13:09:43.933349+0200 PruebaNotificacionPush-IOS[2772:92821] 9.3.0 - [FirebaseMessaging][I-FCM001000] FIRMessaging Remote Notifications proxy enabled, will swizzle remote notification receiver handlers. If you'd prefer to manually integrate Firebase Messaging, add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist, and set it to NO. Follow the instructions at:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#method_swizzling_in_firebase_messaging
to ensure proper integration.
2022-08-01 13:09:43.942140+0200 PruebaNotificacionPush-IOS[2772:92827] 9.3.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS800023] No pending snapshot to activate. SDK name: app_measurement
"FCM token Optional(\"ey-QYQRCnUzNl_l0LmqVVn:APA91bHykEIK4vPCj2XAgg8ewm05z389wzo4GHQZEun3xk4l8p_TyDa4yXbvgwgx_OpqM8rTr4_34vpa9lv5z6nkDgXEPfgHE2hxna_Hq9DW6xTYQJLuI24oh4-inLGMIWxTy-fKC6hL\")"
2022-08-01 13:09:44.030453+0200 PruebaNotificacionPush-IOS[2772:92831] 9.3.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS023012] Analytics collection enabled
2022-08-01 13:09:44.030616+0200 PruebaNotificacionPush-IOS[2772:92831] 9.3.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS023220] Analytics screen reporting is enabled. Call Analytics.logEvent(AnalyticsEventScreenView, parameters: [...]) to log a screen view event. To disable automatic screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseAutomaticScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean) in the Info.plist
2022-08-01 13:09:44.664705+0200 PruebaNotificacionPush-IOS[2772:92822] [] nw_hash_table_apply called with null table
2022-08-01 13:09:44.665514+0200 PruebaNotificacionPush-IOS[2772:92822] [] nw_hash_table_apply called with null table, dumping backtrace:
        [arm64] libnetcore-2736.12.1
    0   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000018209f2f0 __nw_create_backtrace_string + 116
    1   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000018187d820 nw_hash_table_apply + 2676
    2   libnetwork.dylib                    0x0000000181dc8450 EE6D5599-5B6E-3AAC-ABC7-05F56B4EE2FB + 6030416
    3   libnetwork.dylib                    0x0000000181da4a9c EE6D5599-5B6E-3AAC-ABC7-05F56B4EE2FB + 5884572
    4   CFNetwork                           0x00000001815b552c _CFURLStorageSessionCopyIdentifier + 14364
    5   libnetwork.dylib                    0x0000000181997eb8 EE6D5599-5B6E-3AAC-ABC7-05F56B4EE2FB + 1638072
    6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000100f6c94c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000100f6e1c8 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000100f77560 _dispatch_workloop_invoke + 2448
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000100f81630 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 852
    10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001da5bef38 _pthread_wqthread + 284
    11  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001da5beaa4 start_wqthread + 8
```

Espero que me ayudéis, un saludo

Comment: ¿Cuál necesito? En los tutoriales que he visto no ponen ninguno

Comment: Si editas el `plist` como código agregas esto `<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>remote-notification</string>
    </array>` o sino desde Xcode en la configuración del proyecto. En el simulador no llegan las notificaciones.

Comment: he añadido lo que me has dicho y en el log ahora me sale esto:           2022-08-03 08:46:52.694228+0200 PruebaNotificacionPush-IOS[579:15654] 9.3.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS800014] Cannot get flag for unregistered flag. SDK name, flag name: app_measurement, session_stitching_token_feature_enabled

Comment: ¿Podrías compartirme el código de un programa completo que funcione bien y yo le cambie el archivo de firebase? gracias

Comment: Intentaste con el tutorial oficial de [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client)? O con el ejemplo en [GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/tree/master/messaging/)

Comment: Ya me funciona, el problema que tenia era que el certificado .p8 que usaba esta caducado. Borre el viejo y añadi uno nuevo y ya me funciona. Gracias, saludos